# Unable to use numpy in sublime text 3 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text-3, anaconda

I installed the following two softwares on ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS:
-sublime text 3.2.2
-anaconda 3

When I am running the following code on sublime text:
import numpy

I am getting the error:
ImportError: No module named numpy

On windows 10 however, the sublime text is able to import numpy & I don't get any errors. Kindly help. I want to code in sublime text but I am unable to import numpy.

Comment: Sublime Text is only an editor. Your code is actually interpreted by a Python interpreter, which is telling you it doesn't know the module `numpy`. First step would be the figure out which interpreter is used. Second step would be to install the module `numpy`. Doesn't Anaconda have a package manager? Once you have figured this out, please review the question. More (relevant) information makes it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the same problem on my Windows 10, SublimeText 3 64-bit and
>   Anaconda3 64-bit running `conda` Sublime Text package. Here is a
>   workaround:
>
> You can try reinstall the `numpy` python package in the working python
>   environment (env). For example, if you're working on `mypython` env,
>   open the Anaconda Command Prompt and do this:
>
> `conda activate mypython`
>
> then use `pip` to reinstall `numpy`:
>
> `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy`
>
> then try again in Sublime Text, thing should be fine.

Quoted from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021516/numpy-importerror-using-sublime-text-with-anaconda).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a simple method that worked

1. Make sure that pip in installed by using the command `line which -a`. If not installed, try to install anaconda
2. On Sublime text, go to `Tools->Build System`, and select Automatic.
   Sublime text will automatically figure out the correct paths needed.